# Hide counter dots of UIPageViewController on last page

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm making a first tour view with a PageViewController, showing the counter dots at the bottom of the view.

How can I

1. Hide the dots **only in the last page** ? and
2. Adjust the height of the view to fit the full screen?

My last page will be the log in view of my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIPageControl` and hide it when you reach at last page. You can detect last page view delegate methods.
You can find if current page is last page in this delegate method

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{

 }
```