# How to hide dots on last view of UIPageViewController SWIFT

Tags: swift, swift2, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I want to be able to hide the pagination dots on the last view of a UIPageViewController. There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391401/hide-dots-on-final-page-of-uipageviewcontroller-swift) which has already asked it but it is never answered.

If someone could just give me an overview of how this is achievable.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        pageControl.hidden = true
        print(pageControl.hidden)//Always is false
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use the UIPageViewControllerDelegate method:

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages()
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    view.addSubview(pageControl)
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
}

func numberOfPages() -> Int {
    return 4 //your number of pages
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (index == numberOfPages()-1){
          pageControl.hidden = true
    }else{
          pageControl.hidden = false
    }
}
```

too you can migrate to icarousel its very powerful and easily to implement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLvZbXOAZQY

Comment: Thanks, although now I am getting error:   'Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>, Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' to expected argument type 'Int'' on the 'numberOfPages' line

Comment: numberOfPages is that, you can use a constant or a method like me: 
func numberOfPages() -> Int {
        return 4
    }

Comment: Sorry I am confused. 'numberOfPages' is 4. so I have just replaced 'numberOfPages()-1' with 3. What else can I do?

Comment: Thanks for this update, although it is telling me the same first error which I said ^^^

Comment: because is the index, if you have 4 pages the indexes are: 0 1 2 and 3, 3 is the index of the last page

Comment: ok thanks. again I am getting the same error:  "Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>, Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' to expected argument type 'Int''

Comment: Also the 'pageControl.hidden = true' never works. It always stays false. I only works if you use it in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: @HenryBrown are you sure? this property can be change anywhere, and not only with Pager, with anyone element, UIView, UIButton etc

Comment: Yes I'm sure, if you see the question I have provided above he is having the same problem as me. He is not sure why either

Comment: @HenryBrown try to put the control into a view as subview, and hidde the view, maybe works it for you

Comment: No this also doesn't work I tried it. It also stays as false even though it is turned true.

Comment: sorry bro! it worked for me, i need see your project to identify what things its wrong...

Comment: Could you update your code with what you used as I might be getting it wrong and it not I can send you? Thanks for your help man

Comment: @HenryBrown you use the datasource to show the control? or use an independent element?, i use an independent element its more flexible.

Comment: I have updated my code with what I have done, pageControl.hidden is always false even when I have tried to turn it to true.

Comment: Also I put this function inside the datasource

Comment: I put it inside the independent element and it is not now printing true but it still does not hide. It's like it can't happen...